# MYSQL Linebreak

Tags: php, mysql

in my case MYSQL doesn't "accept" the line breaks when updating a string with php.

This is how I added the string into the MYSQL db

```
<?php
  $text = $_POST['textarea']; // my string
  nl2br($text); // replacing php linebreaks with html linebreaks
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE `example` SET `string` = '$text'"); 
?>
```

Now I want to fetch this string and display it.

```
<?php 
 $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `X` = 'Y'");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 $display = $row['string'];
 print $display;
?>
```

Somehow there are no linebreaks displayed.

So I looked with phpmyadmin what the db received:

```
 This is a sample text 
 somewhere here should be a html linebreak
```

I tried to edit this field and suddenly the linebreaks where shown. I edited nothing an just saved it. After this the linebreaks were shown:

```
 This is a sample text<br>
 somewhere here should be a linebreak
```

**I'm so confused. Please explain it to me**

Comment: Are you saving the result of the `nl2br()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not replacing `$text` with the result of `nl2br($text)`

try...

`$text = nl2br($text);`